# Returning a new object if new operator wasn't used

Tags: javascript, oop, google-chrome, object, v8

I have got a "class" (function) in js named `Foo` that create objects. As it is used very frequently, I want it to avoid requiring the `new` keywoard being used when new instances of it are to be created: `Foo(something);` instead of `new Foo(something);`.

I got this to work in Firefox with:

```
function Foo(arg) {
    if (this instanceof Window)
        return new Foo(arg);

    //Object construction here.
    this.bar = "Hello " + arg;
}
```

Now I can create instances of Foo just by calling it as a function.

```
console.log(Foo("World").bar); //Output "Hello World" in console.
```

While this is working in FF, it does not in Chrome and I did not dare testing IE yet.

The problem in chrome is that `window` is really of type `DOMWindow` in chrome

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Window is not defined
```

and `this instanceof DOMWindow` does not work in chrome because for some reason it gives:

```
ReferenceError: DOMWindow is not defined
```

I have also tried using `!(this instanceof Foo)` and `typeof this` always seems to give `"object"`.

How can I reliably detect if the `new` keyword was omitted when calling `Foo` on all browsers?

Update: `!(this instanceof Foo)` does work, I just had a stray `return this` in my real `Foo` function.

Comment: using `!(this instanceof Foo)` works for me (Chrome, Safari, Firefox on Mac). That code: `function Foo() { console.log(this instanceof Foo) }` will log `false` for the execution of `Foo()` and `true` for `new Foo()` in the browsers above.

Comment: @ZER0 yea, i just realised that I have had a stray `return this` in my function that prevent it from working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing this being an instanceof Foo works in Chrome 20, FF 12, and IE 8, and should work fine:

```
function Foo(arg) {
    if (!(this instanceof Foo)) return new Foo(arg);

    //Object construction here.
    this.bar = "Hello " + arg;
}

var foo = Foo('World');
var baz = new Foo('Baz');

console.log(foo.bar);
console.log(baz.bar);
```

As a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/YSEFK/

Comment: That didn't work for me before. But now I did figure out why. I had a stray `return this` at the end of the function. This ofc is a much neater way.

Answer (score 2):

I've not tested, but perhaps something like this would work?

```
var realWindow = this;

function Foo(arg) {
    if (this === realWindow)
        return new Foo(arg);

    //Object construction here.
    this.bar = "Hello " + arg;
}
```

You'll want to make sure `realWindow` is declared outside of any scopes to avoid possible clashes with `this`, of course.

In general though, although this *is* clever, I wouldn't recommend doing it just to save a few characters of typing. It obfuscates the code for future developers and is generally not good practice.

Comment: It depends on what you want. For frameworks like jQuery this is extremely comfortable - imagine if you had to use `new $()` instead of `$()` all the time.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, you're correct, of course. That's why I said "in general". There's almost always a case when breaking a rule or a best practice is okay and even recommended. :)

Comment: Yup, this works, thanks a lot. as ThiefMaster has suggested, it does make sense in some cases.

Comment: Can I ask why this was downvoted? My answer is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

What about invert the condition?

```
function Foo(arg) {
    if (!(this instanceof Foo))
        return new Foo(arg);

    //Object construction here.
    this.bar = "Hello " + arg;
}
```

Comment: This works, but you have to repeat the name of the function. Of course you could use `arguments.callee`, but that won't work in ES strict mode.

Comment: I just replied to the OP needs. Personally speaking, I prefer to use `Object.create` and then `apply` the `constructor` on the new instance. In that way you don't need to repeat yourself, and you can also create an utility function that do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

The way you should be doing this is by checking the current instance against its own type:

```
function Foo(...args...) {
    if (!(this instanceof Foo)) {
        return new Foo(...args...);
    }
    ...do stuff...
}
```

It saves from trying to check against the global object, and works in almost any context (although might not make sense in others):

```
var a = {};
Foo.call(a);
```

What should this return? in my example it will return a new `Foo` instance, although you might *not* want it to create a new `Foo`.